# GoRouter in Flutter not recognizing root path deep links without a trailing slash

Tags: flutter, dart, next.js, vercel, flutter-go-router

I'm experiencing an issue with deep linking in a Flutter app, particularly when using GoRouter for navigation. My web app is built with **Next.js**, hosted on **Vercel**, and uses a custom domain (`www.example.com`). I've set up deep linking following the [official Flutter documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/set-up-app-links), including adding `assetlinks.json` to the `/public/.well-known` directory and configuring `AndroidManifest.xml` as follows:

```xml
<meta-data android:name="flutter_deeplinking_enabled" android:value="true" />
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="http" android:host="www.example.com" />
    <data android:scheme="https" />
</intent-filter>
```

With this setup, deep links work as expected, opening the app from URLs shared in other apps. However, the issue arises when integrating GoRouter for in-app navigation with the following basic setup:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp.router(routerConfig: router));

final router = GoRouter(
  routes: [
    GoRoute(
      path: '/',
      builder: (_, __) => Scaffold(appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Home Screen'))),
      routes: [
        GoRoute(
          path: 'details',
          builder: (_, __) => Scaffold(appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Details Screen'))),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ],
);
```

Navigating to `www.example.com/details` works flawlessly, but attempting to open `www.example.com` to reach the HomeScreen (`'/'` path) triggers a `GoException`:

```
GoException: no routes for location: https://www.example.com
```

Upon investigation, I found that GoRouter receives an empty string instead of `'/'` for the root path. Here's the state at the time of the exception (logged within `onException` of GoRouter):

```
state.error: null
state.path: null
state.fullPath:
state.uri: https://www.example.com
state.topRoute: null
state.extra: null
state.matchedLocation:
state.pageKey: [<'topLevel'>]
state.pathParameters: {}
state.name: null
```

Interestingly, navigating to `www.example.com//` (with a double slash) correctly opens the root route (`'/'`). Neither `www.example.com` nor `www.example.com/` (with a single slash) works as expected. It seems GoRouter anticipates a trailing slash in the domain, but my URL doesn't include one, resulting in routing issues.

**Question**: What could be causing this discrepancy? I am not sure where should I look for the potential cause - because I am not sure if this is an issue with Vercel, Next.js, or GoRouter. Any insights or solutions to ensure the root URL correctly routes to `'/'` in GoRouter would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to add:

```dart
initialLocation: '/',
```

to your GoRouter and see if that helps?

#### Edit:

You could also try to use the redirect function like:

```dart
redirect: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
  // if the path is null or empty, go to '/'
  if(state.fullPath?.isEmpty ?? true) return '/';
  // otherwise try to go wherever we were trying to go before
  return null;
}
```

Comment: I have the same issue and have your suggestion added, but go_router still tries to route to the empty path instead of '/'.

Comment: I added an edit with how you could add a redirect function to your GoRouter. Maybe that would work for you then?

Comment: Sounds interesting, but I'm unable to try it. Turned out that we only needed to catch a specific deeplink, so we removed the default path from the configuration.

Comment: Haha. Sometimes it be like that. Glad you guys found a solution!